# Erlang: Timer - How to get seconds until expiry by the TRef?

Tags: erlang

Is there a way in Erlang to get the number of seconds (or milliseconds) until a timer expires using the timer reference?

Example: the code starts a timer and, after a while, I want to check how much time is left to expire.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`erlang:read_timer/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#read_timer-1) to get the number of milliseconds until the timer expires:

```
1> TRef = erlang:start_timer(60000, self(), hello).
#Ref<0.2346158170.2350907396.218361>
2> erlang:read_timer(TRef).
55824
```